# My app keeps screen on

Tags: android, screen

My android app is able to run on the bakground and I'd like it to do so wenever the user stops interacting with the phone.
I the app is open and the user does nothing with it for x time, I expected Android to lock the screen (which is what i want).
However, the app simply keep th screen on. Why?

I do not use `android:keepScreenOn="true"` anywhere on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you acquiring a WakeLock ?

If yes you should use `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` instead `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` or `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`  the first lets the screen go off, the others don't

Comment: No, I'm not using a wake lock. I'm not doing anything related tot his behaviour, that's why I find it strange not to lock the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out it was my fault, not the apps.

I had enabled 'Keep screen awake while charging', and since I had the phone connected to the computer, the screen never locked...

I'll leave this here in case someone else is in the same situation.